# Best way to modify a file when using pipes?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I often have shell programming tasks where I run into this pattern:

```
cat file | some_script > file
```

This is unsafe - cat may not have read in the entire file before some_script starts writing to it. I don't really want to write the result to a temporary file (its slow, and I don't want the added complication of thinking up a unique new name).

Perhaps, there is there is a standard shell command that will buffer a whole stream until EOF is reached? Something like:

```
cat file | bufferUntilEOF | script > file
```

Ideas?

Comment: Um, xargs should do the trick, right?

Comment: I don't believe so. Well, maybe it does, but its documentation says the problem it solves is handling cases where the command argument limit is exeeded. It doesn't say that it buffers all of stdin before opening stdout.

Comment: I think there are options to xargs that deal with the buffering size.

Comment: BTW, slurping all of the input might lead to a SEGV or SIGBUS due to an out of memory.

Comment: That's possible. But let's assume that I'm just processing source code files one at a time, many of which may exceed the interprocess buffer size (usually 65536 bytes), and my computer has multiple gigabytes of memory available.

Comment: Writing to a temporary file is not any bit slower than writing over an existing file, you'll use twice the disk space though. Moving the temp file back is just a simple rename, not a copy as long as they're on the same mount point.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-there-a-way-to-modify-a-file-in-place

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for [sponge](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/moreutils/).

Comment: That looks like a good solution except that I don't want to require all the users of my scripts to install additional dependencies (or compile any code). -Isn't there an alternative using standard utilities or builtin shell features?

Comment: I don't recommend sponge. If any command in your pipeline (other than sponge) fails (for example, due to syntax error, invalid arguments, etc.), it erases the file, and you end without both the original and the destination file.

Comment: /tmp may be mounted in memory (at least under Linux). In this case I would hope that this could be really fast. Not sure about /tmp in Cygwin though. Does Cygwin hold that in memory?

Comment: @Julinao - The problem is not sponge, its the shell i) sponge < file > file  , causes file to be truncated. Similarly  cat file | b | c | sponge > file , also gets truncated.  Bash truncates the file before sponge gets to see the input. ii) cat file | sponge file ,  works fine.

Comment: @user48956, I don't think that's the failure mode Juliano was describing. Think instead about `sed '...invalid-syntax...' <infile | sponge infile` -- if `sed` fails (exits early because it was given an invalid input), `infile` still gets cleared. Whereas with `if sed '...invalid syntax...' <infile >"$tmpfile"; then mv "$tmpfile" infile; else rm "$tmpfile"; fi` will leave `infile` unmodified if `sed` has a nonzero exit status.

Answer (score 8):

Like many others, I like to use temporary files.  I use the shell process-id as part of the temporary name so that if multiple copies of the script are running at the same time, they won't conflict.  Finally, I then only overwrite the original file if the script succeeds (using boolean operator short-circuiting - it's a little dense but very nice for simple command lines).  Putting that all together, it would look like:

```
some_script < file > smscrpt.$$ && mv smscrpt.$$ file
```

This will leave the temporary file if the command fails.  If you want to clean up on error, you can change that to:

```
some_script < file > smscrpt.$$ && mv smscrpt.$$ file || rm smscrpt.$$
```

BTW, I got rid of the poor use of cat and replaced it with input redirection.

Comment: Thanks -- that's a nice trick. You'll leak a file if some_script fails though. Need to handle that case:

   " ( some_script < file > smscrpt.$$ && mv smscrpt.$$ file ) || \rm -f smscrpt.$$ "

Still, would prefer something like: " (some_script < file) | bufferToEOF > file " because (i) its way easier to read, (ii) I don't have to remember to put in error checking (iii) I believe it would run quite a bit faster under Cygwin because of the Godawful slow file access.

Comment: @stuartreynolds - someone else posted about sponge and you rejected that because it's not standard.  There is nothing standard that does what you want prefer.

Comment: @klatchko - I think something like Sponge *is* the answer I'm looking for (with the caveats I mentioned -- its not really easy for me to use it widely). IMO, if there's really nothing that does what sponge does, *and* the functionality of sponge is fundamental to shell scripting (buffering to avoid file corruption sounds pretty fundamental to me), then probably it should be part of bash, or the standard GNU toolset (in which case I'm hoping someone will point out why we don't need sponge at all... anyone?). Do I *really* have to make a temporary file to do this?

Comment: @stuartreynolds - if you want something standard as of today, then yes, you need temporary files.  I disagree that buffering is fundamental because you get your necessary behavior with temporary files (and given how command lines work, temporary files are better because you can preserve your original file if there's an error).  Finally, if Cygwin is so broken that file rename is too slow, that is the issue that should be fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Using a temporary file is the correct solution here. When you use a redirection like '>', it is handled by the shell, and no matter how many commands are in your pipeline, the shell is free to delete and overwrite the output file before any command is executed (during pipeline setup).

Answer (score 5):

Another option is just to read the file into a variable:

```
file_contents=$(cat file)
echo "$file_contents" | script1 | script2 > file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `mktemp(1)` or `tempfile(1)` saves you the expense of having to think up unique filename.

Answer (score 2):

In response to [the OP's question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089877/best-way-to-modify-a-file-when-using-pipes#comment2022535_2089976) about using `sponge` without external dependencies, and building on [@D.Shawley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2090173/2877364), you can have the effect of sponge with only a dependency on `gawk`, which is not uncommon on Unix or Unix-like systems:

```
cat foo | gawk -voutfn=foo '{lines[NR]=$0;} END {if(NR>0){print lines[1]>outfn;} for(i=2;i<=NR;++i) print lines[i] >> outfn;}'
```

The check for `NR>0` is to truncate the input file.

To use this in a shell script, change `-voutfn=foo` to `-voutfn="$1"` or whatever syntax your shell uses for filename arguments.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat "$1" | gawk -voutfn="$1" '{lines[NR]=$0;} END {if(NR>0){print lines[1]>outfn;} for(i=2;i<=NR;++i) print lines[i] >> outfn;}'
```

Note that, unlike real `sponge`, this may be limited to the size of RAM.  `sponge` actually buffers in a temporary file if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Using a temporary file is IMO better than attempting to buffer the data in the pipeline.

It almost defeats the purpose of pipelines to buffer them.

Comment: Well, maybe. Sounds like a religious argument though. I know all of the files easily fit within a tiny portion of the main memory (my shell script will operate over each source file in a very large SVN repository). 
The temporary file will make it run twice as slow as necessary (at least within Cygwin).

Comment: That may be.  If your code is going to always be used in the way you expect it to, then it makes sense to make judicious trade-offs...

Comment: @stuartreynolds: Using a temporary file will NOT make it run slower, except perhaps for some negligible constant time for renaming the file back to its original name.

Comment: That's a good point... If you're doing copy's instead of renames then you may be taking an unnecessary performance hit.

Comment: @Juliano. I've found renaming files to be VERY slow in windows (Cygwin). (Many many times slower than Linux on the same machine). As a rule of thumb, I try to avoid it if operating over very many files and if the user is waiting while the script runs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `mktemp`. Something like this will work:

```
FILE=example-input.txt
TMP=`mktemp`
some_script <"$FILE" >"$TMP"
mv "$TMP" "$FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is to use a temp file.  However, if you want another approach, you can use something like `awk` to buffer up the input into memory before your application starts receiving input.  The following script will buffer the all of the input into the `lines` array  before it starts to output it to the next consumer in the pipeline.

```
{ lines[NR] = $0; }
END {
    for (line_no=1; line_no<=NR; ++line_no) {
        print lines[line_no];
    }
}
```

You can collapse it into a one-liner if you want:

```
cat file | awk '{lines[NR]=$0;} END {for(i=1;i<=NR;++i) print lines[i];}' > file
```

With all of that, I would still recommend using a temporary file for the output and then overwriting the original file with it.

Comment: This is extremely unreliable (likely to cause data loss), because `> file` truncates `file` **before `awk` starts running**, not when it first prints output at the end of execution.

Comment: Compare to the answer by @cxw, which makes awk do the work of opening the output file and thus avoids this problem.